# Getting invalid times arguement error when running inside a loop but not outside

Tags: r, xml, list, loops, sapply

I can successfully run this xml parsing process outside of a loop
#find all items and store as a list

```
page <- read_xml ("sample.xml")    
items<-xml_find_all(page, "//d1:REPORT/d1:VEHICLEs/d1:ACRSVEHICLE/d1:PASSENGERs/d1:PASSENGER")

#extract all children's names and values

nodenames<-xml_name(xml_children(items))

contents<-trimws(xml_text(xml_children(items)))

#Need to create an index to associate the nodes/contents with each item

itemindex<-rep(1:length(items), times=sapply(items, function(items) {length(xml_children(items))}))

#store all information in data frame.

df<-data.frame(itemindex, nodenames, contents)
```

However when I try to put it in a loop (many xml in the directory but not all have values for each column) I get this error:

```
build_dfs <- function(xml_file) {

  # PARSE DOC AND ASSIGN XPATHs

  doc <- read_xml(xml_file)

  xpath_occupants <- "//d1:REPORT/d1:VEHICLEs/d1:ACRSVEHICLE/d1:PASSENGERs/d1:PASSENGER"

 

  # PEOPLE TABLE

  items <- xml_find_all(doc, xpath_occupants, xml_ns(doc))  #extract all children's names and values

  nodenames<-xml_name(xml_children(items))

  contents<-trimws(xml_text(xml_children(items)))

  #Need to create an index to associate the nodes/contents with each item

  itemindex<-rep(1:length(items), times=sapply(items, function(items) {length(xml_children(items))}))

  #store all information in data frame.

 

  # RETURN A NAMED LIST OF DATA FRAMES

  list(occ = occ)

}

 

# RETRIEVE XML FILES

xml_files <- list.files(file.path("U:", "tmp", "tst"), pattern = "[.]xml")

 

# PASS EACH XML FILE INTO METHOD

data_list <- lapply(xml_files, build_dfs)
```

I get

```
Error in rep(1:length(items), times = sapply(items, function(items) { :

  invalid 'times' argument
```

I cannot provide the XML files easily, but what would potentially be the reason for this error? I assume it is something related to the `itemindex<-rep(1:length(items), times=sapply(items, function(items) {length(xml_children(items))}))` command. How do I create an index to associate the notes and contents with each item in a way that works inside a loop?

Comment: you could try printing `sapply(items, ...)` to see what it looks like. you would get that error if you had an `NA` or maybe you are getting a `NULL` value which makes the times argument a different length than `1:length(items)`

Comment: I'm guessing that the `sapply` call might be returning a list.

Comment: @rawr I believe the problem is that some of the XML files have no values/children for items. In that case, how would I run this loop but only for those where the length of xml children is not null?

Comment: Maybe use a `tryCatch` function to return NULL in case of an error and/or use `seq_along(items)` to catch cases where `length(items)` is NULL.

Comment: but `length(NULL)` is 0, and `rep(1:3, times = c(1, 0, 1))` does not give this error. `rep(1:3, times = c(1, NA, 1))` does and so does `rep(1:3, times = c(1, 1))`. `rep(1:3, times = list(1, 1, 1))` also works but `rep(1:3, times = list(1, 1, NULL))` does not (with a different error)

Comment: @user12728748 how would i put that in the command? I am new to R I am sorry

Comment: @rawr what do you mean by your last comment? It is possible I have an NA actually as well, not sure. If so how would I figure it out?

Comment: print the object you are giving to `times = ` as I said in the first comment